# 32 bit RGBA numpy array from PIL image

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Say I load an image as:

```
> image = Image.open('temp.png')

<PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1200x600 at 0x112F0C488>
```

Notice that the image dimensions are `1200x600`.

I would like to retrieve this image as a 2D numpy array, where each entry holds a **32** bit integer.

If I do:

```
np.array(image).shape
```

I get:

```
(600,1200, 4)
```

How can I convert this to a 32-bit RGBA 2D numpy array?

Comment: I tried the code but I got the shape as `(600, 1200, 4)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Indexing

You're misunderstanding the way that NumPy indexes images. NumPy prefers [row-major indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (*y*, *x*, *c*) for images [for the reasons described here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues):

> The drawback of [column-major indexing] is potential performance penalties. It’s common to access the data sequentially, either implicitly in array operations or explicitly by looping over rows of an image. When that is done, then the data will be accessed in non-optimal order. As the first index is incremented, what is actually happening is that elements spaced far apart in memory are being sequentially accessed, with usually poor memory access speeds.

If you prefer to use column-major indexing (*x*, *y*, *c*) and don't mind the potential performance penalty, then use [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) to permute the indices:

```
np.array(image).transpose((1, 0, 2))
```

But the NumPy documentation recommends that you just get used to it:

> We recommend simply learning to reverse the usual order of indices when accessing elements of an array. Granted, it goes against the grain, but it is more in line with Python semantics and the natural order of the data.

#### 2. Colour channels

The third axis of the array gives you the 4 colour channels in each pixel, here the values (*red*, *green*, *blue*, *alpha*). This is more useful for most applications than a single 32-bit number: for example, you can extract the alpha channel by writing `image[...,3]`.

If you really want the 32-bit colour values, then you can use the [`ndarray.view` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view) to get a view of the same image data with a different `dtype` and then use [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) to drop the last axis (which is now redundant):

```
a = np.array(image)
a.view(dtype=np.uint32).reshape(a.shape[:-1])
```